# Can I use scanf() before calling a function?

Tags: c

This is my code and what I want to do is (1)Take two numbers, (2)Multiply both numbers, (3)Return the product. It should work well without the scanf() but now I'm trying to use the scanf() to input a number via the terminal. Anyone knows what's wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int multiply(int num1, int num2) {
    int product = num1 * num2;
    return product;
}

int main() {

    scanf("%d %d", num1, num2);
    int result = multiply(num1, num2);
    printf("%d x %d = %d", num1, num2, result);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried running the code and it says undeclared num1 and num2. Doesn't num1 and num2 get declared in the multiply function?

Comment: `num1` and `num2` are parameters of the `multiply` function. They are not in-scope in `main`. You need to declare some variables to store those values, and then pas them to `multiply`.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh the chapters and sections on variables, scope and life-time in your beginners book. And see just about any example using `scanf`.

Comment: In addition to the above, `scanf` requires **pointers/addresses** to put the input values into. So you'll need to pass `&num1` etc.

Comment: Does your compiler emit any warnings when you try to compile this? If yes, read and understand them. If not, your compiler is ancient and you should upgrade right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want this:

```
int main() {
    int foo, bar;
    scanf("%d %d", &foo, &bar);     // you forgot the & 
    int result = multiply(foo, bar);
    printf("%d x %d = %d", foo, bar, result);

    return 0;
}
```

- you forgot the & in front of the variables with `scanf`. It's explaind somewhere in your C book
- variables declared in `multiply` are only visible (and they even only exist) inside of `multiply`. This is also explaind in your C book in the chapters dealing with functions.

BTW the code below is equivalent to the code above. The variables `num1` and `num` declared in `main` are not related at all to the variables `num1` and  `num2` in `multiply`, they just happen to have the same name.

```
int main() {
    int num1, num2;
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);     // you forgot the & 
    int result = multiply(num1, num2);
    printf("%d x %d = %d", num1, num2, result);

    return 0;
}
```